# Angular component communication

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having trouble to make two components communicate in Angular, and I can't see where I am making a mistake.

To be more specific I have a table(one component) and I want on click on a row to open a modal window(separate component) with the clicked row details. I have done all the wiring the modal window opens but no data is displayed.

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  posts: Post[];
  selected: any;

  selectRow(post) {
    this.selected = post;
    document.getElementById('modalActivator').click();
  }

  private setPosts(posts) {
    this.posts = posts;
  }

  constructor(
    private restCallService: RestCallService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.restCallService.getPosts().then(posts => this.setPosts(posts))
  }

}
```

Table HTML:

```
     <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let post of posts;"
                (click)="selectRow(post)">

                <td>{{post.userId}}</td>
                <td>{{post.id}}</td>
                <td>{{post.title}}</td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <app-table-row-expanded> [postFromParent]="selected"</app-table-row-expanded>
```

The modal is not opened optimally but could this be the problem for no data communication?

```
export class TableRowExpandedComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() postFromParent: Post

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

I will spare you the whole modal HTML. This is what sits in the modal body:

```
 <p>{{postFromParent?.body}}</p>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

PS, I am using Angular CLI with Eclipse, and already some weird bugs have appeared (running code not compiling unless I close and reopen the file ie. but this doesn't feel to be the issue here)

Comment: Is "TableRowExpandedComponent" your dialog?

Comment: From the code you show here does not look like your components are in a parent-child structure. You can take a look on how component interaction works [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: Yes,  "TableRowExpandedComponent" is the child.
@BogdanC There is a relationship. Look at the last line of the first HTML snipet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a slew of ways to get this to behave how you want. My favorite for a modal is to expose a public open method in the modal component. This will let you call it directly with data based on any conditions you like. As example setup could be

```
export class TableComponent {
  @ViewChild('modal') modal;

  selectRow(post) {
    this.modal.open(post);
  }

}

<app-table-row-expanded #modal> [postFromParent]="selected"</app-table-row-expanded>
```

The #modal provides a reference to your component which is accessed by the @ViewChild decorator. Now you just need to create your open method in the modal component as such

```
export class TableRowExpandedComponent implements OnInit {

  public open(post) {
     // whatever logic to display your stuff here
  }
}
```

You'll also be able to access any @Inputs posted to the component normally

Comment: Just tried it and it works as a charm. I passed in `post` as you suggest and inside a child components method and  i added `postFromParent = post`.
Although this works I am still curious though why my original code did not work, so if you or anyone has an idea I would still be interested.